# sql query error incorrect syntax

Tags: sql

i am trying the below query but i am getting error like incorrect syntax at SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader .. please correct me where i am wrong

```
string querystring = "SELECT ImageName FROM dbo.ProfilePic WHERE UserName = @UserName & IsActive = 'Y' order by ID Desc";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querystring, con);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Session["UserName"].ToString());


            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",
           reader[0]));

                ViewBag.ProfilePic = reader[0];
            }

            reader.Close();
```

updated with all suggested answers

Comment: change all == to = in your query e.g. UserName == @UserName

Comment: and there should be a space between "order" and "by".

Comment: and I am not sure "&&" operator is right either. It should be "AND".

Comment: thank you ... is what i did to assign the Imagename to viewbag is correct??

Comment: with all changes i get the same error incorrect syntax near =

Comment: Post your updated code. Did you change DESCENDING to DESC? I would suggest learning the syntax of SQL: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL doesn't need the double equal signs.

```
SELECT ImageName FROM dbo.ProfilePic WHERE Username = @UserName
```

Comment: Still using the & vs AND. Here's the SQL to use, 

    "SELECT ImageName FROM dbo.ProfilePic WHERE UserName = @UserName AND IsActive = 'Y' order by ID Desc"

Comment: thank you friend... sorry for irritating you people.. till now i wrote them in linq its the reason for all this confusion... any way thank you friends for all your help

Answer (score 0):

in `SQL` you don't need to use double equal sign to compare values and `&&` is wrong, then this is wrong:

```
string querystring = "select ImageName from dbo.ProfilePic where UserName == @UserName && IsActive == 'Y' order by ID descending";
```

and this is true:

```
string querystring = "select ImageName from dbo.ProfilePic where UserName = @UserName AND IsActive = 'Y' order by ID desc";
```

Comment: orderby should be order by

Answer (score 0):

```
            string querystring = "select ImageName from dbo.ProfilePic where UserName =       
            @UserName AND  IsActive = 'Y' order by ID DESC";
            // on sql compare oprator not need to '==' sign 
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querystring, con);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Session["UserName"].ToString());
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",
               reader[0]));
                // when you assign reader value to any object you must assign while DataReader read not after DataReader close
                ViewBag.ProfilePic = reader[0];

                }

                reader.Close();
```

**EDIT**
try

```
string querystring = "select ImageName from dbo.ProfilePic where UserName like '@UserName' AND  IsActive = 'Y' order by ID DESC";
```